# Research paper has Supervised and Unsupervised Learning definition

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, unsupervised-learning, supervised-learning

I am looking for some Research paper or books have good, basic definiton of what Supervised and Unsupervised Learning is. So that i am able to quote these definition in my project.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would make a reference to the following book: Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach (3rd Edition) 3rd Edition by Stuart Russell and Peter Norvig. In more detail in Chapter 18 and in pages 693 and on there is an analysis of supervised and unsupervised learning.  About unsupervised learning:

> In unsupervised learning, the agent learns patterns in the input 
>       even though no explicit feedback is supplied. 
>       The most common unsupervised learning task is clustering: 
>       detecting potentially useful clusters of input examples. 
>       For example, a taxi agent might gradually develop a concept 
>       of “good traffic days” and “bad traffic days” without ever being 
>       given labeled examples of each by a teacher

While for supervised:

> In supervised learning, the agent observes some example input–output
>   pairs
>       and learns a function that maps from input to output. In component 1 above,
>       the inputs are percepts and the output are provided by a teacher 
>       who says “Brake!” or “Turn left.” In component 2, the inputs are camera 
>       images and the outputs again come from a teacher who says “that’s a bus.”
>       In 3, the theory of braking is a function from states and braking actions 
>       to stopping distance in feet. In this case the output value is available 
>       directly from the agent’s percepts (after the fact); the environment
>       is the teacher.

[The examples are mentioned in the text above.](http://file:///C:/Users/c.athanasiadis/Downloads/a154ffbcec538a4161a406abf62f5b76-original.pdf)

Comment: What a good reference! Thank you so much for another great option, sir.

Answer (score 1):

Christopher M. Bishop, "Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning", p.3 (emphasis mine)

> Applications in which the training data comprises examples of the input vectors along with their corresponding target vectors are known as **supervised learning** problems...
>
> In other pattern recognition problems, the training data consists of a set of input vectors x without any corresponding target values. The goal in such **unsupervised learning** problems may be to discover groups of similar examples within the data,
> where it is called *clustering*, or to determine the distribution of data within the input space, known as *density estimation*, or to project the data from a high-dimensional space down to two or three dimensions for the purpose of *visualization*.

Which is as good as you can get. Basically, the most noticable difference is whether we have labels wrt. which we want learning model to optimize. If we don't have some of the labels, it's still can be described as weakly-supervised learning. If no labels are available,the only thing left is to find some structure in the data.

Comment: Thank you so much, sir. By the way, i found my own answer version in "Machine Learning For Dummies, IBM Limited Edition" book, at part "Approaches to Machine Learning" of  chapter 1 "Understanding Machine Learning". It has simpler definition that seem easier to understand for beginer like me. Link to the book: [Machine Learning For Dummies, IBM Limited Edition](https://www.ibm.com/downloads/cas/GB8ZMQZ3)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Pavel Tyshevskyi for the answear. Your answer is perfect but it seem a littel but hard to understand for beginers like me.

And after hour of searching, i found my own answer version in "Machine Learning For Dummies, IBM Limited Edition" book, at part "Approaches to Machine Learning" of chapter 1 "Understanding Machine Learning". It has simpler definition and has example that can help me to understand better a bit. Link to the book: [Machine Learning For Dummies, IBM Limited Edition](https://www.ibm.com/downloads/cas/GB8ZMQZ3)

> **Supervised learning**
>
> Supervised  learning  typically  begins  with  an  established  set  of data and a certain understanding of how that data is classified. Supervised learning is intended to find patterns in data that can be applied to an analytics process. This data has labeled features that define the meaning of data. For example, there could be mil-lions of images of animals and include an explanation of what each animal is and then you can create a machine learning appli-cation that distinguishes one animal from another. By labeling this data about types of animals, you may have hundreds of cat-egories of different species. Because the attributes and the mean-ing of the data have been identified, it is well understood by the users that are training the modeled data so that it fits the details of the labels. When the label is continuous, it is a regression; when the data comes from a finite set of values, it known as classifica-tion.  In  essence,  regression  used  for  supervised  learning  helps you understand the correlation between variables. An example of supervised learning is weather forecasting. By using regression analysis, weather forecasting takes into account known historical weather patterns and the current conditions to provide a predic-tion on the weather.
>
> The algorithms are trained using preprocessed examples, and at this point, the performance of the algorithms is evaluated with test  data.  Occasionally,  patterns  that  are  identified  in  a  subset of the data can’t be detected in the larger population of data. If the model is fit to only represent the patterns that exist in the training subset, you create a problem called overfitting. Overfit-ting means that your model is precisely tuned for your training data but may not be applicable for large sets of unknown data. To protect against overfitting, testing needs to be done against unforeseen or unknown labeled data. Using unforeseen data for the test set can help you evaluate the accuracy of the model in predicting outcomes and results. Supervised training models have broad applicability to a variety of business problems, including fraud detection, recommendation solutions, speech recognition, or risk analysis.
>
> **Unsupervised learning**
>
> Unsupervised learning is best suited when the problem requires a massive amount of data that is unlabeled. For example, social media  applications,  such  as  Twitter,  Instagram,  Snapchat,  and.....